# How to read Google Chrome bookmarks externally?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Did not love much for XMarks as it copied and duplicated the bookmarks.
The Chrome's own feature of synchronizing the bookmarks over multiple devices is good.

Is there a way to extract the links I have bookmarked so far in Chrom browser with the Categories that I have created and classified for my bookmarks?

Does any API exist to read those Google Chrome's bookmarks directly from their server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the raw links or the bookmarks transfered to another browser. If you want the bookmarks for another browser, use the import option on that particular browser. IE and FF gives you the option on first run to import 'local' bookmarks from another browser. As for the raw links, you may have to look into your 'ApplicationData' folder of chrome, not exactly sure which folder... try: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: \Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data\Default\Bookmarks as JSON file.